# Etymology of "broma"

Tags: etimología

According to dictionaries, this word comes from the Ancient Greek word **βρῶμα** (*brôma*), which has the following meanings:

1. a shipworm (Teredo navalis) that bores into wooden piers, ships, etc.
2. that which is eaten, food, meat
3. (dentistry) cavity

None of these translations have anything funny about them. How, then, did **broma** come to mean joke in Spanish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the right source with definition #1. That shipworm eats into things (the ship hull). A `broma` is played on someone and *eats* that person a little bit (lets say that the **annoyance** of the joke *eats* him, or gets into him, like that worm that eats the wood).

The origin of the word is closer to mockery and deceit, thus implying that a `broma` would annoy someone.

Also, the word `abrumar` has apparently the same etymology.

> **Abrumar**
>
> 1- Agobiar con un peso grave.
>
> 2- Producir tedio o hastío.
>
> 3- Producir asombro o admiración.

So with `abrumar` you can be *overloaded* by both positive and negative emotions. [This reference](http://laboratoriodeescritura.com/blog/es/2008/04/de-una-etimologia-subacuatica/) explains the etymology, but basically, the same way that a ship would be *dragged* or  by the perforations in the hull done by these shipworms (an encumbrance or impediment to sail), a person would be by emotions (something in you that becomes a *burden*).